# remove arrow buttons for product viewpage in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

please visit the link : http://steel.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/universal-beams-338/universal-beams.html

Below Product images, you can see "up arrow" and "4 images" and "lower arrow" button. I want to delete "up arrow"

and "lower arrow" button and "4 images".

This is my product view page code view.phtml = http://pastebin.com/KnFipAK3

please give me solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images con't come from `view.phtml`. They are rendered by `view/media.phtml`.

If you want to remove only the arrows just don't start the carousel.
There is this in `media.phtml`. Remove it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel3').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 1
    });
});
```

I you want to remove all images just remove the element `ul` with the id `mycarousel3`

Comment: Hi,

Unfortunately your solution did't worked. please check the media.phtml file = http://pastebin.com/VEJY12ay

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3483987. You are editing the wrong `media.phtml`. This may be replaced by a third party module. You can see what template you need to edit by turning on the template path hints. http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/

Comment: Thanks for your reply for this website, Debug =>yes or no option, no template path hints option at all under Debug.

Comment: @user3483987 Read the post in the link I posted. You need to change the scope of the config from the top left dropdown. The template path hints do not appear in the global scope. Select your main website.

Comment: now please check again and help me , ehat i have to do http://steel.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/universal-beams-338/universal-beams.html

Comment: @user3483987 You have to edit `frontend/default/Universal Beams work 8/template/framework/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` and do what I suggested in the answer.

Comment: Hi, there is no jquery function in media.phtml http://pastebin.com/VEJY12ay, please give me any idea.

Comment: Strange. Are you sure you are editing the right file? You can search for the text `jQuery('#mycarousel3').jcarousel({` in your files and you will find the one that needs to be modified.

Comment: Hi, Really i can't able to find in media.phtml file, i am searching in right file . can you please and tell me from which line, i have to edit. there is no jquery function.

Comment: Is i have to search jquery function in skin folder?

Comment: I am sorry, i searched in same file, not inside framework.... now its working....

Comment: Hi, please check this.... why the template path is still displaying here : http://steel.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/steeel-angelss.html

Comment: Clear the cache.

Comment: thanks, please visit "http://steel.newtrendzonline.com/" , below footer , I want a block in the footer, inside i want to display follow us. what changes i have to do?

Comment: @user3483987. That is a totally different question. you shouldn't mix questions. Keep them separate and simple.

Answer (score 1):

It's very Simple. You are in wrong File

Step 1 : Open media Folder in `catalog/product/view/media.phtml`.

Step 2 : Find the **"more-views"** Div.

Step 3 : Comment the More-views div.

Step 4: Refresh the cache and run frontend.

Comment: Hi,

Unfortunately your solution did't worked. please check the media.phtml file = http://pastebin.com/VEJY12ay

Thanks in advance